# Having some kind of dictionary issue

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to have my program prompt a user to enter a course number and get multiple answers regarding that course number.

```
    def main():
    courses = {}
course= {'CS101' : ['Room Number: ' '3004', 'Instructor: ' 'Haynes', 'Meeting Time: ' '8:00 a.m.'],

              'CS102' : ['Room Number: ' '4501', 'Instructor: ' 'Alvarado', 'Meeting Time: ' '9:00 a.m.'],
              'CS103' : ['Room Number: ' '6755', 'Instructor: ' 'Rich', 'Meeting Time: ' '10:00 a.m.'],
              'NT110' :['Room Number: ' '1244', 'Instructor: ' 'Burke', 'Meeting Time: ' '11:00 a.m.'],
              'CM241' :['Room Number: ' '1411', 'Instructor: ' 'Lee', 'Meeting Time: ' '1:00 p.m.'],
              }

search_course = str(input('Enter course number: '))
for key, value in course.items():
    print(key, value)

main()
```

The user is prompted to enter a course number. He should get the room number, instructor, and meeting time, like this:

```
enter a course number: CS101
   Room Number 6755, Instructor: haynes, meeting time: 8:00 am.
```

Instead I get this:

```
Enter course number: cs101
CS101 ['Room Number: 3004', 'Instructor: Haynes', 'Meeting Time: 8:00 a.m.']
CS102 ['Room Number: 4501', 'Instructor: Alvarado', 'Meeting Time: 9:00 a.m.']
CS103 ['Room Number: 6755', 'Instructor: Rich', 'Meeting Time: 10:00 a.m.']
NT110 ['Room Number: 1244', 'Instructor: Burke', 'Meeting Time: 11:00 a.m.']
CM241 ['Room Number: 1411', 'Instructor: Lee', 'Meeting Time: 1:00 p.m.']
```

how do I get the course number to equal out to my result?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. It's unclear what that code is, but it doesn't seem to drive at the result you mention and I'm not sure what issues you might be having getting there, because you haven't explained the problem yet!

Comment: After fixing your dictionary definitions, you can do `print(' '.join(course_num[search_course]))` will print out `Room Number: 3004 Instructor: Haynes Meeting Time: 8:00 a.m.)`

Comment: @downshift unless you're having to support pre-NT-era clients, there's no reason to use Python2 anymore. The lack of `dict.iteritems` and the line `print(...)` in OP's code informs that he's in Python3, so that should be `print(' '.join(...))`

Comment: (caveat: I do support a win98 machine at my office, so I have py2.6 on my system. Ugh the shame)

Comment: @Adam: There are a number of other reasons to still use Python 2 beyond what (apparently) you are able to imagine.

Comment: @martineau bad reasons don't count ;)

Comment: What should be inner-dictionaries look like dictionary-list hybrids and are not valid Python literals.

Comment: @AdamSmith But `str(input(...))` informs that they're *not* using Python 3 or that they don't know what they're doing and thus can't be trusted :-P

Comment: They are valid literals, but not in the way that you intend. They are simple lists of strings since `'Room Number: ' '3004'` is implicitly concatenated to the string `'Room Number: 3004'`. It is not the key-value pair `'Room Number' :  '3004'` in a dictionary, which is what I think you want.

Comment: @JohnColeman I've actaully tried that and it only resulted in syntax errors.

Comment: You have 2 issues: you are using `[,]` instead of `{,}` and you have things like `'Room Number: ' '3004'` rather than `'Room Number':  '3004'` Note carefully the position of the second quote mark.

Comment: Is the example output for cs101 `Room Number 6755` just a typo, for that dictionary shouldn't it be `Room Number 3004`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each dictionary key corresponds to a list of related information for that key, the problem seems to be properly separating and places quotes between strings in each list.

```
course_num = {'CS101': ['Room Number: 3004', 'Instructor: Haynes', 'Meeting Time: 8:00 a.m.'],
              'CS102': ['Room Number: 4501', 'Instructor: Alvarado', 'Meeting Time: 9:00 a.m.'],
              'CS103': ['Room Number: 6755', 'Instructor: Rich', 'Meeting Time: 10:00 a.m.'],
              'NT110': ['Room Number: 1244', 'Instructor: Burke', 'Meeting Time: 11:00 a.m.'],
              'CM241': ['Room Number: 1411', 'Instructor: Lee', 'Meeting Time: 1:00 p.m.']}

search_course = input('Enter course number: ').upper()
print(' '.join(course_num[search_course]))
```

Demo:

```
Enter course number: CS101
Room Number: 3004 Instructor: Haynes Meeting Time: 8:00 a.m.
```

Which matches your required output.

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    courses = {
        'CS101' : ['Room Number: ' '3004', 'Instructor: ' 'Haynes', 'Meeting Time: ' '8:00 a.m.'],
        'CS102' : ['Room Number: ' '4501', 'Instructor: ' 'Alvarado', 'Meeting Time: ' '9:00 a.m.'],
        'CS103' : ['Room Number: ' '6755', 'Instructor: ' 'Rich', 'Meeting Time: ' '10:00 a.m.'],
        'NT110' : ['Room Number: ' '1244', 'Instructor: ' 'Burke', 'Meeting Time: ' '11:00 a.m.'],
        'CM241' : ['Room Number: ' '1411', 'Instructor: ' 'Lee', 'Meeting Time: ' '1:00 p.m.']
    }

    courseNum = raw_input("Enter course number:")
    print "you entered", courseNum

    for key, value in courses.items():
        if(key == courseNum.upper()):
            print ", ".join(value)
main()
```

**Result:**

```
sh-4.3$ python main.py                                                                                                                                                      
Enter course number:NT110                                                                                                                                                   
you entered NT110                                                                                                                                                           
Room Number: 1244, Instructor: Burke, Meeting Time: 11:00 a.m.
```

Comment: You see this was another test of mine too. I tried doing this but I only got:  you entered cs101

Comment: Note that keys in a dictionary are case sensitive so you would need to use CS101 not cs101. If you want to support case insensitive matching you can always use upper like this: key == courseNum.upper()